# when flex-direction is column, divs takes all available width. how to prevent this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

See attached snippet.
I need each item to take width space, with respect to content.
flex-items need to be stacked vertically, like in the example.
how to achieve it?

how to do that?

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.green {
  background-color:green;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green"> hello world</div>
  <div class="red"> hello world2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: change it to `flex-direction: row;`

Comment: Add display:inline-table to child elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they still should stack vertically, use `display: inline-flex` and they will size equally by the content of the widest item.

For each row to collapse to their individual content, use i.e. `align-items: flex-start`, and note, this will make them collapse when using `display: flex` too.

Why they stretch to equal width, is because `align-items` defaults to `stretch`, so by using any other value they will size by content

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.green {
  background-color:green;
}
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green"> hello world</div>
  <div class="red"> hello world2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better but still not exactly what i need. it seems it takes the longest flex-item in the column, and make everybody that length.

Comment: @LiranC Updated

Comment: @LGSon nice trick

Comment: wow , interesting how `align-items: flex-start` had anything to do with it with this magic.

Comment: @LiranC Added an explanation why that fixes it